# In Rails, how to calculate durations between 2 UTC times read from mysql

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am using Rails 4. I've read 2 records(**b1** and **b2**) from database. Both them have a column called `build_start_time`, which is defined as `datetime` type in Mysql. The `build_start_time` between **b1** record and **b2** record are like this:

```
2.0.0-p643 :021 > b1.build_start_time
 => Tue, 12 Aug 2014 18:23:31 UTC +00:00

2.0.0-p643 :012 > b2.build_start_time
 => Fri, 15 Aug 2014 10:07:18 UTC +00:00
```

How do I calculate the duration between them in Rails ? Does anybody have an idea?
The result should be something like:

```
b2.build_start_time - b1.build_start_time = 2 days 15 hours 53 minutes 47 seconds
```

Is this possible?

Comment: Depending on your usecase you might want to consider the [`distance_of_time_in_words`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/DateHelper.html#method-i-distance_of_time_in_words) helper.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you can tolerate your answer being off by less than a second you could try using the `to_i` and `ago` methods:

```
def datetime_diff(datetime1, datetime2)
    res = datetime1 <=> datetime2
    if res == 0
        # order doesn't matter in this case
        min = datetime1
        max = datetime2
    elif res < 0
        min = datetime1
        max = datetime2
    else
        min = datetime2
        max = datetime1
    end

    max.ago(min.to_i) # min.to_i returns min in seconds since the epoch
end
```

You figure out which time came first then you return the later of the two times x seconds `ago`, where x is the earlier time in seconds since the epoch. See http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/DateTime.html#method-i-3C-3D-3E